# laravel join multiple tables with nested data

Tags: laravel

I have a situation where I need data within data while doing a DB call.

For example I have a post, that has many comments, but then there is a user to that comment in another table.

So I have

```
$post = Posts::where('id', $id)->with('comments')->first();
```

and Posts model is

```
public function comments()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comments', 'postId', 'postId');
    }
```

This works well, I get the post and all the comments but now I need to get the users for those comments. How would I include that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be

`$post = Posts::where('id', $id)->with('comments', 'comments.user')->first();` 
or what ever you have called the user relation on the comment. or

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['user'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Will always return the user with the comment.

Comment: @Micheal Mano, this is the answer. So simple, thank you for that. Works super well. Nice and clean.